# Firebase push() collections item key, when is it generated?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase push() collections item key, is it generated immediately on client side or after sync done?

eg this code:

```
var messageListRef = new Firebase('https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/message_list');
messageListRef.push({ 'user_id': 'fred', 'text': 'Yabba Dabba Doo!' });
```

And if immediately generated on client side, how can i acquire it immediately? without using callback

Comment: Use are using legacy version. Just check the doc https://www.firebase.com/docs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase's push ids are generated client-side. That's why they continue to work when you're not connected to the server.

See:

- [The 2^120 Ways to Ensure Unique Identifiers](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html)
- [How deal with Firebase offline mode and data push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682329/how-deal-with-firebase-offline-mode-and-data-push/33682815#33682815)
- [In Firebase when using push() How do I get the unique ID and store in my database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768576/in-firebase-when-using-push-how-do-i-get-the-unique-id-and-store-in-my-databas/38768630#38768630)